# How to work with text in MS Word using AutoHotKey?

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, ms-word, autohotkey

When I receive a large text to translate, I wish to use my associative array (dictionary) and highlight all the occurences of the keys and replace them with their respective values.

I created a macro in VBA, and wish to adjust its language to Autohotkey; but no matter the approach I use, Autohotkey sends me a message that “this action is not recognized”, fx the line with oWord.With Selection.Find.Replacement.Font

```
;* the “translated” VBA-code to find all instances of the word “the”, and replace their font color with blue
#IfWinActive ahk_class OpusApp
^!3::
oWord := ComObj("Word.Application")
oWord.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
oWord.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    oWord.With Selection.Find.Replacement.Font
        oWord.Bold = False
        oWord.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
        oWord.Color = wdColorBlue
    oWord.End With
oWord.Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        oWord.With Selection.Find
        oWord.Text = "the"
        oWord.Replacement.Text = "^&"
        oWord.Forward = True
        oWord.Wrap = wdFindContinue
        oWord.Format = True
        oWord.MatchCase = False
        oWord.MatchWholeWord = False
        oWord.MatchWildcards = False
        oWord.MatchSoundsLike = False
        oWord.MatchAllWordForms = False
    oWord.End With
oWord.Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

```
; this is the original (unmodified) code snippet in VBA:
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        With Selection.Find
        .Text = " Ant"
        .Replacement.Text = " ant"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
```

1. Where can I find the guidelines on how to **“translate” each lines of code**?
2. I wish to create a **loop to run through a selected text in MS Word, find all occurrences of Keys in my array**, and replace them with their respective values.

Comment: Well, I wanted to use the code while having the Word application open, and selecting the text (or select all) to run the highlighting loops through.

Comment: “You're better off just preceeding every line with the full object.”
Do you mean changing it to “oWord.Selection.Find”? 
What about the other indented lines? There are similar errors appearing down the script.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an [array](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Arrays.htm) using
`Array = [Item1, Item2, ..., ItemN]`

[Loop](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm) through an array with `Loop N { ... }` where N is the number of times to loop. To make it easy, I used the array count, `Array.Length()`.

Enumerations from Word and VBA cannot be used in AutoHotKey, all enumerations must be replaced with their numeric value. This makes the code less readable, but it must be done. Keywords `True` and `False` are lower case in AutoHotKey (`true` and `false`).

Operators like `=` must be converted into their AutoHotKey notation, like `:=`.

Named parameters wont work. `Execute Replace:=...` can't be used to shortcut past the first few parameters. Instead, you have to leave a bunch of commas to get to the parameter spot for `Replace`. e.g. `Execute(,,,,,,,,,,2)`

VBA `With` Statements, and any other VBA Statements, cannot be used in AutoHotKey script. Instead, each line of the AutoHotKey script must make full use of your saved Object variables and its properties. `oWord.Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold` instead of `With oWord.Selection.Find.Replacement` ... `.Font.Bold`

```
^!3::
    FindArray := ["The", "And", "She"]
    ReplaceArray := ["abc", "def", "xyz"]
    
    oWord := ComObj("Word.Application")
    TextRange := oWord.ActiveDocument.Range

    TextRange.Find.ClearFormatting
    TextRange.Find.Forward := true
    TextRange.Find.Wrap := 1
    TextRange.Find.Format := true
    TextRange.Find.MatchCase := false
    TextRange.Find.MatchWholeWord := false
    TextRange.Find.MatchWildcards := false
    TextRange.Find.MatchSoundsLike := false
    TextRange.Find.MatchAllWordForms := false
    
    TextRange.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    TextRange.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold := false
    TextRange.Find.Replacement.Font.Underline := 0
    TextRange.Find.Replacement.Font.Color := 16711680
    
    Loop % FindArray.Length() {
        TextRange.Find.Text := FindArray[A_Index]
        TextRange.Find.Replacement.Text := ReplaceArray[A_Index]
        TextRange.Find.Execute(,,,,,,,,,,2)
        
    }
Return
```

To Highlight the found matches, add the following lines before the loop.

```vb
oWord.Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex := 6
TextRange.Find.Format := true
TextRange.Find.Replacement.Highlight := true
```

Comment: the code works well, and you have provided a good and thorough explanation. 
1. do you know it it´s possible to work with associative arrays?
2. in case I want to create another Macro in Word and use AHK, do you know of any Instructions for Use, which goes beyond your explanation?

Comment: @NotAColdSun AHK can load Com objects from other scripting languages, so you could potentially use Lists, Dictionaries, and other fancy array objects. I don't have much experience in doing so, and I can't provide advice about the best way to do so.

Comment: @NotAColdSun If you follow the advice from my answer, you should be able to convert VBA macros into AHK script without trouble. Learning AHK is very easy because they have great documentation on their [website](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) and when you run the app. Honestly, whenever I have problems in AHK, I check their website first and can usually find an article explaining how to solve it.

Comment: I also wish to highlight all the found appearances in red, and have added the following line just below the “Font.Color”.
TextRange.Find.Replacement.HighlightColorIndex := 6
Unfortunately, I get this message: 
Error in line 41 in this file: 
The leftmost character above is illegal in an expression. 
This program will exit. 
Any idea why it does not work, and how to make it work?

Comment: @NotAColdSun I have updated my answer with an example. `HighlightColorIndex` isnt a valid property of the `Replacement` object. To highlight the matches, you set  `...Replacement.Highlight := true` which will then highlight the matches based on the application's default highlight color. So if you want red, you have to change the default.