# Autohotkey: Find and replace multiple words/instances in LibreOffice (I have an example in MS Word)

Tags: loops, text, autohotkey, libreoffice, ini

This is the code snippet (a VBA macro adjusted for autohotkey) I use to loop through a text in a Word document and highlight all occurrences of certain words (keys → values), which is useful for my translation work.

```
!k:: ; hotkey → find and replace keys with with their respective values
oWord := ComObj("Word.Application")
TextRange := oWord.ActiveDocument.Range

TextRange.Find.ClearFormatting
TextRange.Find.Forward := true
TextRange.Find.Wrap := 1
TextRange.Find.Format := true
TextRange.Find.MatchCase := false
TextRange.Find.MatchWholeWord := false
TextRange.Find.MatchWildcards := false
TextRange.Find.MatchSoundsLike := false
TextRange.Find.MatchAllWordForms := false

TextRange.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
TextRange.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold := false
TextRange.Find.Replacement.Font.Underline := 0
TextRange.Find.Replacement.Font.Color := 0 ; black font
ini := A_ScriptDir "\zO.ini" ; ini: find keys and replace them with values:
IniRead txt, % ini, Blackflex ; the keys and values are from an .ini file
For each, line in StrSplit(txt, "`n") {
 part := StrSplit(line, "=") ; syntax for key-value pairs is: key1=value1, etc.
 textRange.Find.Text             := part[1] ; keys
 textRange.Find.Replacement.Text := part[2] ; values
 textRange.Find.Execute(,,,,,,,,,, 2)
}
```

Another good example (keys and values from simple arrays) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74633364/how-to-work-with-text-in-ms-word-using-autohotkey/74634497#74634497:%7E:text=%5E!3%3A%3A%0A%20%20%20%20FindArray,Replacement.Highlight%20%3A%3D%20true).

**How can I change the code so it can do exactly the same thing in LibreOffice Writer?**

I have asked chatGPT and tried different approaches, but to no avail. if you have any algorhytm or ways to translate a LibreOffice Basic or VBA language into AutoHotkey, feel free to share it with me.

Comment: Do you want to write the code in AHK or in a LibreOffice macro? If the latter, then a good place to start learning LO Basic is https://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php. Start by looking at the Writer macros in chapter 7.

Comment: I just want to write a code that works in LibreOffice, iow: a Macro in LibreOffice, but translated into AHK, just like I did in the example codes I showed for MS Word. 
The link you sent me has nothing specific for LibreOffice, but... if I read and learn about the Macros in OpenOffice, is the language same as in LibreOffice?

Comment: Why translate a macro to AHK? The first lines of code you show in your question boil down to "we will be working on the current active document". If you already have a document open in Writer, why not run the replace macro right here in LibreOffice? And yes, the programming language - all the listings given in the specified book, will work correctly in LibreOffice.

Comment: Because I have my arrays (arrays.ahk) and .ini files saved on my computer, and AHK reads them and searches all occurrences of the words in MS Word, like this: 
ini := A_ScriptDir "\zO.ini" 
IniRead txt, % ini, Blackflex
For each, line in StrSplit(txt, "`n") {
 part := StrSplit(line, "=") ; syntax for key-value pairs is: key1=value1, etc.
 textRange.Find.Text             := part[1] ; keys
 textRange.Find.Replacement.Text := part[2] ; values
 textRange.Find.Execute(,,,,,,,,,, 2)
Maybe I can do the same thing in LibreOffice, I´ll have a look at it. Still new to programming.

Comment: I would suggest that you migrate the contents of your .ini files to Calc spreadsheets - this will allow you to easily add and change pairs. You will also be able to sort the dictionaries in descending order by the length of the searched words. The fact is that the most common problem with mass replacement according to the list is the repeated replacement of already processed words. Here's an example:one of the first substitutions will be "cat" for "dog", and the subsequent substitution of "caterpillar" for "bulldozer" will no longer work, because the text will contain the words "dogerpillar"

Comment: So true, it's useful to sort by length of a word/expression. AHK has an IniWrite function, so I have a separate hotkey to add selected text into a hotkey into a special segment - maybe this will be possible in calc, too. I think in this case I'll use FileAppend to the topmost empty cell; and when replacing words, looping through entries in a particular column.

Comment: I use this script (AHK v2) to append selected text to a segment called Lingua in .ini file. 
^+l::
{
A_Clipboard := ""
Send "^c"
ClipWait
A_Clipboard := A_Clipboard
Sleep(150)
Clip1 := Trim(A_Clipboard)
Sleep(150)
IniWrite Clip1, A_ScriptDir "/zFL.ini", "Lingua"
Sleep(300)
clip2:= A_Clipboard
ToolTip("Copied&saved! Lingua " clip2)
Sleep(1500)
ToolTip()
}
Could you please help me to adjust the code to write/append into Calc/Excel file (also into a segment called Lingua)?
Which file type would you suggest for storing words/terms?

Comment: Questions on this site should be more specific. Otherwise, it sounds like you are asking for someone to write code for you, which is not acceptable here. Have you attempted to write the code yourself after studying resources such as the one I mentioned earlier? If so, then edit the question to post the Basic code you have so far, and mention a specific problem you have encountered.